# Textbox in custom toolbar

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

Is it possible to put textbox control in custom toolbar in Excel. I have created an Add-in that shows this toolbar. What I want to do is when user types in textbox Add-in should call a procedure or function depending what user has typed.

I would like to do it in VBA in MS Excel.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using ? (Ribbon UI or Command Bars?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out:

```
Sub test()
    Set myControl = CommandBars("Test").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlEdit, Before:=1)
    With myControl
        .Caption = "Search"
        .OnAction = "Tester"
    End With
End Sub


Sub Tester()
    MsgBox "I am gonna search for: " & CommandBars("Test").Controls(1).Text
    CommandBars("Test").Controls(1).Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Excel 2007 and have implemented IRibbonExtensibility::GetCustomUI then you can use the following XML to define an edit box in your Addin GUI:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="MyTab" label="My Tab">
                <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group">
                    <editBox id="MyEditBox" getText="MyEditBoxCallbackgetText" label="Editbox Label" onChange="MyEditBoxCallbackOnChange"/>
                 </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: That looks good. I should consider to upgrading to 2007. Thank you.

Comment: When I get a chance I can give you the code for 2003, walking out the door right now ;)